# Auto scale Service Fabric Stateless Service?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, stateless, azure-vm-scale-set

Is there any way to set up auto scaling of stateless services in Service Fabric? I know you can add more nodes to the cluster using Scale sets and auto scaling, but what about adding more instances of a service to the cluster as traffic increases?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd also like an answer to this but as far as I'm aware you have to do it yourself (i.e. write a service (or eternal program) which monitors service load and creates/removes instances accordingly.

Comment: From what I can tell, you are correct. Surprisingly sad.

Comment: @Mardoxx Azure Service Fabric is built on top of Virtual Machine Scalesets. VMSS has the ability to auto scale based on performance counter metrics. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview

Comment: @Dismissile this doesn't auto scale services' instances though just the VM's doesn't it? Setting everything to -1 is a bit of workaround rather than a solution imo -- what if you want one service to scale 2x another, or just have 5 instances when load is high and 1 otherwise etc..?

Comment: If you have one instance per node then it would scale that way. If you are not using -1 for the instance count then you are correct in that it will not scale automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the instance count to -1 should do the trick. You'll have 1 service instance per node. If the node count changes, so will the service count.

Comment: If the stateless service is a web api then -1 is probably the best way to scale it. If you are specifying the port in the ServiceManifest, then you can't really go beyond the number of nodes without running into port conflicts. However, if your service is a stateless service that is just doing background processing then you could set the number of instances to be more than the number of nodes so -1 might not be what you want in that case. You would have to figure out some way to divide the work among those instances, though.

Comment: Thanks for the great information, I would still like to know if its possible to add these service instances when needed automatically, rather than spinning up x number of services at the strat